# How to print the FULL output, not collapsed output, of type error messages and definitions in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Here is an example of viewing a type definition which is ellipsed:

```
const yx: undefined[] | string[] | number[] | ({
    partial: true;
    children: (... | {
        complete: boolean;
        partial: false;
        dive: boolean;
        like: AST.Term;
        name: string;
        nest: ...[];
    } | {
        partial: true;
        children: string[];
        like: AST.String;
    } | {
        ...;
    })[];
    like: AST.Term;
} | ... 6 more ... | {
    ...;
})[] | ... 20 more ... | ({
    partial: true;
    children: (... | {
        complete: boolean;
        partial: false;
        dive: boolean;
        like: AST.Term;
        name: string;
        nest: ...[];
    } | {
        partial: true;
        children: string[];
        like: AST.String;
    } | {
        ...;
    })[];
    like: AST.Term;
} | ... 2 more ... | {
    ...;
})[]
```

Notice the `... 20 more ...` and such. They are not clickable/expandable so I cannot see what is in there to debug. How can I better debug a type definition like that? I used `ExpandRecursively` like so to see it:

```
const yx: ExpandRecursively<X['children']>


// expands object types one level deep
export type Expand<T> = T extends infer O
  ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] }
  : never

// expands object types recursively
export type ExpandRecursively<T> = T extends object
  ? T extends infer O
    ? { [K in keyof O]: ExpandRecursively<O[K]> }
    : never
  : T
```

Likewise, how can I get the error message to expand all its output in TypeScript?

```
Argument of type 'X' is not assignable to parameter of type 'X["children"]'.
  Type 'ASTPartialType<AST>' is not assignable to type 'X["children"]'.
    Type 'ASTTemplate_PartialType' is not assignable to type 'X["children"]'.
      Type 'ASTTemplate_PartialType' is not assignable to type '(ASTInput_PartialType | ASTTerm_Type)[] | (ASTTerm_Type | ASTClassReference_Type)[] | (ASTTerm_Type | ASTString_Type)[] | ... 21 more ... | number[]'.
        Type 'X' is not assignable to type '(ASTInput_PartialType | ASTTerm_Type)[] | (ASTTerm_Type | ASTClassReference_Type)[] | (ASTTerm_Type | ASTString_Type)[] | ... 21 more ... | number[]'.
          Type 'ASTPartialType<AST>' is not assignable to type '(ASTInput_PartialType | ASTTerm_Type)[] | (ASTTerm_Type | ASTClassReference_Type)[] | (ASTTerm_Type | ASTString_Type)[] | ... 21 more ... | number[]'.
            Type 'ASTTemplate_PartialType' is not assignable to type '(ASTInput_PartialType | ASTTerm_Type)[] | (ASTTerm_Type | ASTClassReference_Type)[] | (ASTTerm_Type | ASTString_Type)[] | ... 21 more ... | number[]'.
              Type 'X' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
                Type 'ASTPartialType<AST>' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
                  Type 'ASTTemplate_PartialType' is missing the following properties from type 'number[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.
```

In there it says `29 more`, `... 21 more ...` a few times, etc.. How can I have it show every single thing so I can tell what's in the union type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For errors you can set to `true` the `noErrorTruncation` flag.
For general inferred types there are some hacks listed here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26238